# How to use Regex and javascript to replace only strings between two pipes ||

Tags: javascript, regex, regexp-replace

I'm trying to create an HTML table using javascript from a String that I will get from a database.
the data is a wiki table like the example I will leave below:

```
||Information Communicated||who||when||Complete|||aa|aa|aa|aa|
```

I've tried using this regex expression: `[^|]*\||(\w+)\||`

but it's selecting all pipes.
I want to get the double pipe with the string between the first || and last || which means in this case

```
||Information Communicated||who||when||Complete||
```

I don't know what is missing but please help me

Comment: ... _"I want to get the string between the first || and last ||"_ ... thus, the OP wants to be `'Information Communicated||who||when||Complete|'` the matching/captured result?

Comment: `\|\|(?<toreplace>.+?)\|\|` will match only text between double pipes

Comment: Sorry i meant the double pipe with inbetween string -> ` ||Information Communicated||who||when||Complete||`

Comment: It should be `\|\|(.*)\|\|` or `\|\|.*\|\|`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/VS1mNa/2).

Comment: Or `\|\|(.*[^|])\|\|`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/VS1mNa/3).